# How to display data inside array of object initially when the page loads in Rxjs?

Tags: javascript, html, rxjs

guys I have made a simple rxjs project using javascript where the user can search game, and filter the data as per his needs. So all filters are working fine but the data does not load initially when the page loads for the first time I also tried using **startWith() operator** to get the results initially when the page load but it is not working as expected. The data only loads when the user searches for data or adds a filter.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-v0/YVjBcbjLN6scjmmJN+h86koeB7JhY4/2YeyA5l+rTdtKLv0VbDBNJ32rxJpsaW1QGMd1Z16lsLOSGI38Rbg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>>
</head>


<body>

    <h1>Games</h1>
    <input type="text" name="" id="search_game" placeholder="search games">
    <label for="">
        <input type="checkbox" id="party">Party</label>
    <select id="studio">
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="Lucid Sheep Games">Lucid Sheep Games</option>
        <option value="Beatshapers">Beatshapers</option>
        <option value="QubicGames">QubicGames</option>
    </select>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <table cellpadding="10">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left;" id="game_name">Name</th>
                <th style="text-align:left;">Released</th>
                <th style="text-align:left;">Genre</th>
            </tr>
        <tbody id="table-content">

        </tbody>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
const { of, fromEvent, ajax: { ajax }, operators: { startWith, switchMap, map, debounce }, combineLatest } = rxjs;

const searchGame = document.getElementById('search_game');
const partyGenre = document.getElementById('party');
const studioInput = document.getElementById('studio')
const studioFlag=true
// const result=search.subscribe(val=>console.log(val))
// search.pipe((switchMap(searchStr=>ajax.getJSON('https://api.sampleapis.com/switch/games', console.log(searchStr)))))
const search = fromEvent(searchGame, 'input').pipe(map(e => e.target.value.toString().toLowerCase()), startWith(''))
// search.subscribe(e=>console.log(e)); to log the input.
const partyGame = fromEvent(partyGenre, 'input').pipe(map(e => e.target.checked), startWith(false));
const studio = fromEvent(studioInput,'change').pipe(map(e=>e.target.value),startWith(''));

const games = ajax.getJSON('https://api.sampleapis.com/switch/games');
// const lowerCaseGames = games.map(games)

//Search input 
combineLatest([games, search]).pipe(map(([games, search]) => games.filter(game => game.name.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1))).subscribe(gamesList => {
    let tableContent = '';
    gamesList.forEach(game => {
        tableContent += `<tr>`;
        tableContent += `<td>` + game.name + `</td>`
        tableContent += `<td>` + (!game.releaseDates.Japan + ' ' + '(Japan)' ? game.releaseDates.Europe + ' ' + `(Europe)` : game.releaseDates.Australia + ' ' + `(Australia)`) + `</td>`
        tableContent += `<td>` + game.genre + `</td>`
        // console.log(game.publishers[0]);
    })
    document.getElementById('table-content').innerHTML = tableContent
    console.log(gamesList);;
})
// Checkbox input
combineLatest([games, partyGame,studio]).pipe(map(([games, partyGame]) => games.filter(game => game.genre[0] === 'Party' ? partyGame === true : partyGame === false))).subscribe(
    gamesList => {
        let tableContent = '';
        gamesList.forEach(game => {
            tableContent += `<tr>`;
            tableContent += `<td>` + game.name + `</td>`
            tableContent += `<td>` + (!game.releaseDates.Japan + ' ' + '(Japan)' ? game.releaseDates.Europe + ' ' + `(Europe)` : game.releaseDates.Australia + ' ' + `(Australia)`) + `</td>`
            tableContent += `<td>` + game.genre + `</td>`
        })
        document.getElementById('table-content').innerHTML = tableContent
    })
    

// Select input
combineLatest([games,studio]).pipe(map(([games,studio])=> games.filter( game=>game.publishers[0] === studio ))).subscribe(
    gamesList => {
        let tableContent = '';
        gamesList.forEach(game => {
            tableContent += `<tr>`;
            tableContent += `<td>` + game.name + `</td>`
            tableContent += `<td>` + (!game.releaseDates.Japan + ' ' + '(Japan)' ? game.releaseDates.Europe + ' ' + `(Europe)` : game.releaseDates.Australia + ' ' + `(Australia)`) + `</td>`
            tableContent += `<td>` + game.genre + `</td>`
        })
        document.getElementById('table-content').innerHTML = tableContent
        console.log(gamesList);
    }
)
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: In RxJs there is a common standard to name observables with a $ at the end. Not only does this make it obvious that an object is an observable it leaves the name available when we unwrap the observables the name is available for function properties. eg: `games$.subscribe(games => doStuffWithGames(games))`. Reusing variable names in function parameters hides the outside objects, is confusing and should be a linting rule that disallows the practice in your project.

Comment: Make sense! I went through the official angular doc: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables , though I am using javascript instead of typescript I should have used $ sign for observables for better readability  of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is with the `studio select`. If you change the value of `studio` and switch back to `all`, the data will not show.

`combineLatest([games,studio]).pipe(map(([games,studio])=> games.filter( game=>game.publishers[0] === studio )))`

the above line of code will return empty, because none of the publishers will exactly match `""`(the initial value of studio). Try the below snippet, it should work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-v0/YVjBcbjLN6scjmmJN+h86koeB7JhY4/2YeyA5l+rTdtKLv0VbDBNJ32rxJpsaW1QGMd1Z16lsLOSGI38Rbg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>>
</head>


<body>

    <h1>Games</h1>
    <input type="text" name="" id="search_game" placeholder="search games">
    <label for="">
        <input type="checkbox" id="party">Party</label>
    <select id="studio">
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="Lucid Sheep Games">Lucid Sheep Games</option>
        <option value="Beatshapers">Beatshapers</option>
        <option value="QubicGames">QubicGames</option>
    </select>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <table cellpadding="10">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left;" id="game_name">Name</th>
                <th style="text-align:left;">Released</th>
                <th style="text-align:left;">Genre</th>
            </tr>
        <tbody id="table-content">

        </tbody>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
const { of, fromEvent, ajax: { ajax }, operators: { startWith, switchMap, map, debounce }, combineLatest } = rxjs;

const searchGame = document.getElementById('search_game');
const partyGenre = document.getElementById('party');
const studioInput = document.getElementById('studio')
const studioFlag=true
// const result=search.subscribe(val=>console.log(val))
// search.pipe((switchMap(searchStr=>ajax.getJSON('https://api.sampleapis.com/switch/games', console.log(searchStr)))))
const search = fromEvent(searchGame, 'input').pipe(map(e => e.target.value.toString().toLowerCase()), startWith(''))
// search.subscribe(e=>console.log(e)); to log the input.
const partyGame = fromEvent(partyGenre, 'input').pipe(map(e => e.target.checked), startWith(false));
const studio = fromEvent(studioInput,'change').pipe(map(e=>e.target.value),startWith(''));

const games = ajax.getJSON('https://api.sampleapis.com/switch/games');
// const lowerCaseGames = games.map(games)

//Search input 
combineLatest([games, search]).pipe(map(([games, search]) => games.filter(game => game.name.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1))).subscribe(gamesList => {
    let tableContent = '';
    gamesList.forEach(game => {
        tableContent += `<tr>`;
        tableContent += `<td>` + game.name + `</td>`
        tableContent += `<td>` + (!game.releaseDates.Japan + ' ' + '(Japan)' ? game.releaseDates.Europe + ' ' + `(Europe)` : game.releaseDates.Australia + ' ' + `(Australia)`) + `</td>`
        tableContent += `<td>` + game.genre + `</td>`
        // console.log(game.publishers[0]);
    })
    document.getElementById('table-content').innerHTML = tableContent
    console.log(gamesList);;
})
// Checkbox input
combineLatest([games, partyGame,studio]).pipe(map(([games, partyGame]) => games.filter(game => game.genre[0] === 'Party' ? partyGame === true : partyGame === false))).subscribe(
    gamesList => {
        let tableContent = '';
        gamesList.forEach(game => {
            tableContent += `<tr>`;
            tableContent += `<td>` + game.name + `</td>`
            tableContent += `<td>` + (!game.releaseDates.Japan + ' ' + '(Japan)' ? game.releaseDates.Europe + ' ' + `(Europe)` : game.releaseDates.Australia + ' ' + `(Australia)`) + `</td>`
            tableContent += `<td>` + game.genre + `</td>`
        })
        document.getElementById('table-content').innerHTML = tableContent
    })
    

// Select input
combineLatest([games,studio]).pipe(map(([games,studio])=> games.filter( game=>game.publishers[0].indexOf(studio) > -1 ))).subscribe(
    gamesList => {
        let tableContent = '';
        gamesList.forEach(game => {
            tableContent += `<tr>`;
            tableContent += `<td>` + game.name + `</td>`
            tableContent += `<td>` + (!game.releaseDates.Japan + ' ' + '(Japan)' ? game.releaseDates.Europe + ' ' + `(Europe)` : game.releaseDates.Australia + ' ' + `(Australia)`) + `</td>`
            tableContent += `<td>` + game.genre + `</td>`
        })
        document.getElementById('table-content').innerHTML = tableContent
        console.log(gamesList);
    }
)
</script>

</html>
```